# Is O(N^2) nested for loop as O(N) while loop possible?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Am I correct in saying that this code will execute in O(N) time? This is to iterate through a map< int, vector< int > >.

```
  int counter = 0;
  unsigned int u = 0;
  unsigned int v = 0;
  bool notDone = true;
  while (notDone) {
    if (u < map.size()) {
      if (v < map.at(u).size()) {
        if (map.at(u)[v] == -1) {
          ++v;
        }
        else {
          ++counter;
          ++v;
        }
      }
      else {
        v = 0;
        ++u;
      }
    } else {
      notDone = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It'd be better if you explained what the goal of this code is.

Comment: Well it depends. What is 'N'? In the double for loop it is the size of the map. In your while loop it is the size of all elements inside the vector. That beeing said, both approaches actually have the same complexity.

Comment: The title of this question is very mysterious

Comment: I don't understand what the question is asking, but I'll point out that naming a variable "notDone" and then setting it to false when you're done is very confusing.  Name your variable `done`, set it to `false`, and then say `while(!done)`.  That's much easier to reason about. But even easier to reason about would be eliminating the variable altogether and replacing it with `while(true)` and `break;`.

Comment: @harold I had a hard time thinking about how to word the question. I have a map of vectors and I want to loop through every element in the map and every element of the vector, but I'm trying to do it in O(N) time.

Comment: OK, where "N" means *what* exactly?  What have you got N of?

Comment: A nested `for` loop does not necessarily cost O(N^2) to execute.  If it does, then restructuring it as a single `while` loop does not necessarily reduce the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @EricLippert Integers

Comment: It won't execute in O(N) time, but it will grow with O(N) complexity so for every 1 element added there are 1 more iterations added to loop.

Comment: Integers in as in Map Keys or Integers as in sum of all vectors?

Comment: @CShark basically a 2D array.

Comment: There isn't just an `N` here. there's also an `M`: The number of `vector<int>`s held within the map.

Comment: You're not understanding the question we're asking you here. When you say "this executes in O(N) time" that N refers to counting *something*. Is N the number of maps? The number of vectors? The number of elements in the average vector? The total number of elements in all the vectors?  There's no such thing as an O(N) algorithm where N doesn't refer to anything; N is a count of *something relevant to your program*, so what is it?

Comment: @EricLippert N would be the integers that would be map "keys", and then iterate through every element in the vector that would be the "value" of the map.

Comment: Then your for loop did complete in O(N) - it iterated over every map key only once. So does your new code.

Comment: If N is the size of the map, then your algorithm is O(N) whether you use while loops or a nested for loop.  **This assumes that the size of the map will grow large, and that every vector will be small**. Is that assumption correct? Remember **the purpose of O notation is to describe program behaviour as the size of the data grows large**.  Are your maps going to get very large and your vectors stay very small?

Comment: @EricLippert That is correct. I was just told that nested for loops ran in O(n^2) always. That is why I was trying to avoid it.

Comment: Then you were either told wrong, or misunderstood. A nested loop runs in `O(N * M)` where N is the number of outer loops and M is the average number of inner loops. **Do you have reason to believe that the size of the vectors increases proportionally as the size of the map increases?** If you known that then `O(N*M)` is equal to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: @yorTsenoJ What you were probably told is that nested loops **over the same container** run in `O(N^2)`, where `N` is the number of elements in that single container. There is no way to express the complexity of iterating two **unrelated** containers using just the single symbol `N`.

Comment: Not also that the complexity of `map.at()` (assuming `map` here is `std::map`, and therefore a binary search tree) is logarithmic in the size of the map, further increasing your overall complexity to `O(N * Log(N) * M)` (using @EricLippert 's definitions for `N` and `M`). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If N is the number of map entries, and TV is the sum of the sizes of all the vectors, then your program is `O(N + TV)` regardless of whether it is written as a "while" or a nested "for".

If N is the number of map entries and MV is the mean of the sizes of all the vectors, then your program is `O(N * MV)` regardless of whether it is written as a "while" or a nested "for".

UPDATE: Commenter Tim notes that `map.at` is `O(lg N)` in the size of the map, and it is called `O(N)` times, so that makes the actual complexities `O(N * lg N + TV)` and `O(N * lg N * MV)` respectively. Thanks!

I do not know enough about the C++ standard library to say if there is a more efficient way; I would suspect that an O(1) iterator over the map exists. If it does, then you could use it rather than your index to iterate the map, and the `lg N` term would vanish again.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you said,

> I have a map of vectors and I want to loop through every element in the map and every element of the vector, but I'm trying to do it in O(N) time.

That is not possible.

If you have M elements in the map and N elements in each of the vectors, you have M*N elements all together. There is no way you can iterate over them in O(N) time.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over the map of length N, and in each loop you iterate over a vector of length M. Assuming all vectors have the same length, your algorithm will run in O(N*M).